# Dataflow template parameters are not working

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have an apache beam pipeline that works fine. I used to run it from cmd line and submit it to Dataflow and it works good.

Now, I want to create a template for my pipeline. I succeed to create the template with the following cmd:

```
python main.py --runner DataflowRunner  --region europe-west3 --project X --temp_location gs://X/tmp --staging_location gs://X/staging --template_location gs://X/templates/ft_mc_etl --paramA "defaultA" --paramB "defaultB" --setup_file ./setup.py --save_main_session
```

and it creates the template file successfully.

After that, when I try to create a job from template in dataflow, I customise my pipeline with paramA with newA, and paramB with newB. And while the execution, I can see in the job info in side bar, in the pipeline option, that the option paramA has value newA and same for B. But during the execution, it takes the default value submitted while creating the template (defaultA and defaultB)

My code looks like this:

```
class UserOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--paramA',
            default='pdefaultA'
        )
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--paramB',
            default='pdefaultB'
        )


pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

        user_options = pipeline_options.view_as(UserOptions)
        paramA = str(user_options.paramA)
        paramB = str(user_options.paramB)
```

Answer (score 2):

When using classic templates, it is necessary to pass parameters around as `ValueProvider` instances in order to replace them at the time of template launch. Otherwise the *values* of the options are frozen at the time the template pipeline is first created.

The new feature of [Flex Templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates) removes this requirement. Now you can write your pipeline code exactly as normal and package it up as a template.

Comment: Thank you Kenn, I came to solve part of the issue, I discovered that while creating the template using that command, I shouldn't pass any parameter in the command line. But in the same time, while creating the template (without submitting the cmd parameters), it does a local check and it flags that they are required (even I'm creating the template not running the pipeline locally). Is this the same classic template limitation that you're talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Can you please clarify what "it flags that they are required" means? Are you getting an error?

It's possible to use a param in a classic template (via the "value provider") and make it required at the same time, there should be no errors.

If your goal is to add a runtime parameter, then yes, you shouldn't provide its value when you create (stage) the template, only when you run a job from the staged template. It's hard to say what the problem is exactly without seeing more code (e.g. **where** in the code do you access `user_options.paramA`?), but make sure you don't access these value providers when/before building the pipeline. The value provider (not the value!) has to be passed to the transform/DoFn and accessed there only in runtime, when the pipeline is already running, because when you stage the template you don't have the actual parameter value yet. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#python) is an example. Note that `templated_int.get()` is called only inside `MySumFn`.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to flex template solved all my issues